# XSS blacklist in php

Tags: javascript, php, xss

I have html code and js in it.
I need to remove all js from html.
My question is: 
Is it enough to filter only js events, js tags script and attributes with "data:" in src or I have to filter something else?

Comment: Do not use a blacklist. Blacklists are unsafe. They get out of date. Use a whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWASP site has the full list here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet